# Am I missing some important fact about symbols in LISP?

Tags: lisp, common-lisp

What is the correct way to do this?

```
(defparameter form1 (list 'baz "hello"))
(setf (car form1) (intern "print"))
(eval form1)
```

What is the significance of || (intern) uses?
What is the significance of #:|| (make-symbol) uses?

If they are just part of the name, what is the rationale of creating a different symbol from that which I have specified?

**Update:**
(intern "PRINT")
works

Comment: Note that you modify literal data. Generally this is undefined in portable Common Lisp and thus should be avoided in Common Lisp programs. You may destructively modify freshly consed lists, by LIST, COPY-LIST and other operations.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The vertical bars are the quotes for symbols. Symbols that you've entered literally in the source code don't use them because the reader turns them into all-caps, and all-caps symbols don't need to be quoted.

The `#:` at the front signifies uninterned symbols, i.e. symbols that don't belong to any package. `intern` puts symbols into the current package. Only symbols of the current package are printed without the name of their package.